# How will i compare today's date with the database date for 48 hrs

Tags: java, date, arraylist, resultset

I have taken today's date by Using

```
Date date=new Date();
```

I have a column in database named `edited_date`,i have taken that date by using `getDate()` in the while loop of rs

```
d=rs.getDate("edited_date");  
(d is declared outside the while loop as Date d=null);
```

i have put this result set into the arraylist.
Now i need to compare today's date with the `"d"` which is in the arraylist as `trow.getEdited_date()`, where trow is the object.
How will i compare today's date with `t.getEdited_date()`.
Their difference should be greater than 48 hrs.Please help!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Duplicates so many questions on SO ...

Comment: i had used if(date.getTime()-d.getTime>millis48hours) where millis48hours=1000*60*60*48,but then i need to compare the arraylist date,which is t.getEdited_date(),how do i do that??

Answer (score 0):

```
int hourInMillisecond = 48*3600000;
Date date = new Date();


if (date.getTime()-d2.getTime() > hourInMillisecond){

}
```

Comment: yes,but the comparison is with the date in the arraylist which am getting as,t.getEdited_date() while iterating the arraylist.how iwll i compare the current time with t.getEdited_date() for 48 hrs

Comment: If trow.getEdited_date() is a java.util.Date in the iteration you can compare a new Date object with your. ex. if (new Date().getTime()-trow.getEdited_date().getTime() > hourInMillisecond){

}

Comment: i tried this ,i get a error saying "THe method getTime() is undefined for the type string" for trow.getEdited_date.getTime()

Comment: Probably because trow.getEdited_date is not a java.util.Date. What type is it?

Comment: thankyou for the help.i converted trow.getEdited_date into a date object by using DateFormat and parse method.It worked then.Thankyou!